# How to make a node script of Newman fail when a test fails

Tags: node.js, jenkins, newman

I have a newman script which works:

```
                var fs = require('fs'),
                newman = require('newman'),

                results = [];

            newman.run({
                reporters: 'cli',
                collection: require('.temp.json'),
                iterationData: './data.jsp',
                reporters: ['cli', 'html'],
                reporter: {
                    html: {
                        export: './newman/htmlResults.html', // If not specified, the file will be written to `newman/` in the current working directory.
                    }
                }
            })
            .on('request', function (err, args) {
                if (!err) {
                    // here, args.response represents the entire response object
                    var rawBody = args.response.stream, // this is a buffer
                    body = rawBody.toString(); // stringified JSON

                    results.push(JSON.parse(body)); // this is just to aggregate all responses into one object
                }
            })
            // a second argument is also passed to this handler, if more details are needed.
            .on('done', function (err, summary) {
                // write the details to any file of your choice. The format may vary depending on your use case
                fs.writeFileSync('migration-report.json', JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
                if(summary.run.failures.length !== 0){
                    console.log("\\rThere are test failures")
                    //here I can exit but the Newman summary isn't showed
                }
            });
```

This script works but even when there are test failures it finished successfully. The test failures are showed but I want to end the script with something like exit code 1 because I will run this in Jenkins and I wan't to check if tests work or not depending on the buildresult colour. How can I do this in node?

Answer (score 0):

Add assertion "Chai" library to your tests and use its methods to assert the result of your tests
read more:
[https://www.chaijs.com/](http://Chaijs)
[https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference](http://Postman%20API%20where%20present%20info%20about%20chai)

```
const chai = require('chai')
 expect = chai.expect;
```

and put an assertion depending on what you want to assert (statusCode, reposneBody etc)
For Instance: assert that you expect your response body will have an array with 3 objects inside

```
.on('request', function (err, args) {
                if (!err) {
                    // here, args.response represents the entire response object
                    var rawBody = args.response.stream, // this is a buffer
                    body = rawBody.toString(); // stringified JSON

                    results.push(JSON.parse(body)); // this is just to aggregate all responses into one object
                    expect(body.array.length === 3).to.equal(true)// **EXAMPLE**
                }
            })
```

or

```
pm.expect(res).to.have.property('code', 200);
pm.expect(res).to.have.property('status', 'OK');
```

both check status code of the response on your request.

Read: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference